# Value Error while creating 10 by 2 matrix using tf.Variable(range(0,20),shape=(10,2))

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow2.0

Code - r = tf.Variable([range(0,20)],shape=(10,2))

Error -
ValueError: The initial value's shape ((1, 20)) is not compatible with the explicitly supplied `shape` argument ((10, 2)).

Comment: This needs code snippets, examples and/or anything reproducible! Language used and more, please use the search function to find similar questions and see how they asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import tensorflow as tf

r = tf.Variable(range(20))
# r = [ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19]

r = tf.reshape(r, shape=(10, 2))
# r = [[ 0  1]
#      [ 2  3]
#      [ 4  5]
#      [ 6  7]
#      [ 8  9]
#      [10 11]
#      [12 13]
#      [14 15]
#      [16 17]
#      [18 19]]
```

Answer (score 0):

*'shape'* parameter is an optional parameter for **tf.Variable()**.
The first param *'initial_value'* is given as a Tensor, or Python object convertible to a Tensor, which is the initial value for the Variable. The initial value must have a shape specified unless *'validate_shape'* is set to **False**.
Once the *'initial_value'* is set, then we can reshape it using **tf.reshape()** method.

> Answering to the above question: reshape before giving it as an input,
> it won't be reshaped automatically based on the *'shape'* value.

```
 r = tf.Variable(np.array(range(0,20)).reshape((10,2)),shape=(10,2))
```

Hope I have answered your question.